# Artifactory Adobe Public repository Set Me Up

Tags: artifactory

Required to get all required Adobe plugin from Adobe public repository through Artifactory
For this Under Set Me Up -> Adobe Public in Artifactory home page.
Now click it provide the password it gives resolution.

curl -u: -O "http://10.32.23.108:8081/artifactory/Adobe-Public/"

However when I try to execute the resolution in a Unix box it fails to download any plugin or jar files though it connects do not give any error but only 0% download.
**Is there any other setting needed for this Adobe Public.**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this curl command? why not using Maven? is the repository created in Artifactory is a Maven repository? please share more details so it will be possible to answer your question

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do but if the goal is to download all the bundles from the artifactory then you will have to enumerate and download each bundle in your script. Simply providing the root path to curl won't really do much. Also, what has this question got to do with AEM as it is tagged under AEM?

Comment: I require to get adobe-public-releases referred by http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public through Jfrog Artifactory.

Comment: The other alternative is following, add it to setting.xml or in POM file.

Comment: Adobe provide following xml script that can be used in POM file or setting.xml to get required files from Adobe-Public. This is provided in link https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/SetUpTheAdobeMavenRepository.html                               
I want to achieve through artifactory.

Answer (score 1):

To proxy the Adobe Maven repository you need to perform the following steps:

1. Create a new [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories) in Artifactory - Admin -> Remote -> New
2. Choose `maven` as the repository type
3. Set a repository key, for example `Adobe`
4. Set the following as the repository URL - `https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public`
5. Click the "Test" button to make sure Artifactory can connect to the Adobe repository
6. Click `Save & Finish`
7. Make sure you can see the new repository in the Artifact Repository Browser. You can expand the tree to see the content of the remote repository.
8. Add the new repository to the `libs-release` virtual repository. This will allow to resolve Adobe artifacts using the `libs-release` repository.
9. If you have not done it already, generate a Maven settings.xml file using Set Me Up. Configure Maven with the generate settings.xml file. For more info see [Maven Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository)

The above steps should allow you to resolve arifacts from the Adobe repository.

You should not use the Maven settings.xml from the adobe [web site](https://repo.adobe.com/). This one is intended to be used when you resolve artifacts directly from their repository and not via Artifactory. There is no need to add the `adobe-public` profile.

This does not affect you `distributionManagement` settings in the pom file. Those are required for deploying your build artifacts.

Comment: Tool -> Generic
Repository->Adobe-Public
Resolve -> curl -uadmin:(generated password) -O "http://ip:8081/artifactory/Adobe-Public/<TARGET_FILE_PATH>"
In setting xml do I need to put resolve value directly or in an xml format as bellow?  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>Some Id</id>
        <name>Name</name>
         curl -uadmin:(generated password) -O "http://ip:8081/artifactory/Adobe-Public/<TARGET_FILE_PATH>"
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

Comment: I have remote repository created for Adobe in Artifactory
Following information. Package Type -> Generic, Repository key -> Adobe-Public, Url -> ttps://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public 
test->connected successfully. Repository layout -> maven-2-default, Remote layout Mapping -> maven-2-default, Include Patterns -> **/*, Exclude Paterns -> None. List remote Folder Item -> Not ticked
Set Me Up for Adobe-Public it shows as above

Comment: The repository type should be maven not generic. Please read my answer and the documentation I linked to it. There is detailed documentation about how to use Maven with Artifactory.

Comment: Created repository Adobe from Admin repositories remote. Package type maven. Repository Layout -> maven-2-default. What needs to be remote layout mapping ? (options -mave-2-default, ivy-default, browser default,..or blank).

Comment: no need to change the remote layout mapping. it should only be used if the remote repository is using a different layout and you need to convert.

Comment: Got the setting.xml file generated from set me up ->Generate Maven Setting. having libs-release value http://ip-address:8081/artifactory/libs-release and libs-snapshot value  http://ip-address:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot. I still find I require to include A D O B E   P U B L I C   P R O F I L E in profiles segment of my POM file. Moreover in distributionManagement segment of my POM file need to add repository with value http://ip-address:8081/artifactory/libs-release and snapshots with value http://ip-address:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local to do the build.

Comment: Even though I add setting.xml in build using command mvn -f mypom.xml deploy -X -s settings.xml

Comment: you need to make sure that the remote repository you created for Adobe is part of the libs-release virtual repository

Comment: Understood the need to add in dependency of repository created for Adobe. But why ADOBE PUBLIC PROFILE is required to add in Profiles segment? When we are adding the required dependencies.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more detailed. I suggest that you will update your question with more details and a clear state of what you have configured and what is still not working. It is impossible to read that information from the comments